# C++ how to make templated code cleaner

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working with highly templated code in C++ and the code is driving me crazy, since I constantly have to mess around with abominations like this:

```
std::pair<typename P<A, B>::const iterator, std::pair<long, typename P<A, B>::const_iterator> p;
```

(no C++11 for tuple)

and this:

```
template <A, B, C, D, E>
class MyClass {
  private:
    P <A, B> p;
    Q <C, D> q;
    // (does nothing with A, B, C, D but has to use the template because
    // this class uses other templated classes P<A, B> and Q<C, D>)
    // ...
};
```

Is there a way to make the code cleaner and more readable like using `typedef` or other tricks?

EDIT:
Think of P and Q as std::maps that i don't know the type.

Here is ~how my code works

```
template<A, B, C, D>
class MapWrapper {
  private:
    std::map< map<A, B>::const_iterator, map<C, D>::const_iterator > _map;

  public:
    void insert_in_map (map<A, B>::const_iterator one, map<C, D>::const_iterator two) {
        _map[one] = two;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, with `typedef` or `using`. But you already said that in the question, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for...

Comment: How do i use typedef to reduce the templates? I can't use using because one side effect of templates is i have to put all the code in the .h

Comment: The long expression `std::pair<...` in your question is invalid...

Comment: It is not invalid. It compiles and runs flawlessly

Comment: There are many different techniques for that. Without more information about your code it is hard to help.

Comment: Basically, i can't change P or Q. only what uses them. It's as if i had a generic std::vector that i don't know the type.

Comment: I added the basic idea of my code using stl classes

Comment: So you just want `typedef map<A,B>::const_iterator key_type;` ?

Comment: Move to C++11, for the love of you and everybody else. :)

Comment: Btw, I don't think you can put an `map<A, B>::const_iterator` as a key for a map, at least not according to the standard.

Comment: ([demonstration of what @ybungalobill said](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28747f1816d40de6))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to rewrite it to

```
template <class P, class Q>
class MyClass {
  private:
    P p;
    Q q;
};
```

and instead uses like

```
MyClass<A, B, C, D, E>
```

change them to

```
MyClass<P<A, B>, Q<C, D>>
```

This, with correct use of typedefs, *may* reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Another option is to pay with runtime performance by applying some type erasure (i.e. use less templates).

**EDIT:** following your edit, in your concrete code, you can generalize your class to work with any pairs of iterators:

```
template<class I1, class I2>
class MapWrapper {
  private:
    std::map<I1, I2> _map;

  public:
    void insert_in_map (I1 one, I2 two) {
        _map[one] = two;
    }
};
```

Depending on the algorithmic part, this may, or may not, make sense.

Comment: One can always add another `template<A,B,C,D> class MyOtherClass` that is a synonym for `MyClass<P<A,B>,Q<C,D>>`.

Comment: But that way I'm just transferring the templating responsibility to whoever uses my code.

Comment: Now that i think about it, it does make more sense to template the class and not the stuff it's templated after.